# При выборе одного из вариантов (например 2) должна запускаться функция game, но при вводе 2 ничего не происходит. Буду очень благодарен!

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
async def game(ctx):
    result = 0
    result_bot = 0
    diler = True
    choice = True
    stavka = True
    balance = 0
    await ctx.send('---BlackJack---')
    await ctx.send('---------------')
    time.sleep(0.6)
    await ctx.send(f'Ваш баланс: {balance}')
    time.sleep(0.6)

    while stavka:
        await ctx.send('Сколько хотите поставить?')
        #.............

@bot.command('menu')
async def menu(ctx):
    await ctx.send('|  Что тебя интересует?  |')
    time.sleep(0.6)
    await ctx.send('===|1|======|2|=======|3|===')
    await ctx.send(' \ Баланс | Black Jack | Поддержка / ')
    menu_s = await bot.wait_for('message')
    if menu_s == "1":
        await balance(ctx)
    elif menu_s == "2":
        await game(ctx)
    elif menu_s == "3":
        await support(ctx)
```

Comment: Заранее огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: Предполагаю что проблема в `menu_s = await bot.wait_for('message')`
попробуй после этой строчки прописать print(menu_s)
а ещё у тебя нету отступов для функции, всё что находится внутри функции game должно иметь отступ

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей print выводит:                                                                                             
 <Message id=982207958748377118 channel=<DMChannel id=966362440570896504 recipient=<User id=788378076500852796 name='krasher12' discriminator='1233' bot=False>> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<User id=788378076500852796 name='krasher12' discriminator='1233' bot=False> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>

Comment: а какое сообщение было отправлено?

Comment: Не совсем понял. Ну в кратце я отправляю боту '2' в консоли ничего не выводится, как будто остановилось. А print( menu_s ) выводит:                                                                                        
<Message id=982207958748377118 channel=<DMChannel id=966362440570896504 recipient=<User id=788378076500852796 name='krasher12' discriminator='1233' bot=False>> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<User id=788378076500852796 name='krasher12' discriminator='1233' bot=False> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>